# Jquery mobile not working with angular js in a razor view

Tags: jquery-mobile, razor, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having problems while using jquery mobile tags and angular js in my razor view page.

```
<div  app.directives data-role="page" id="service" class="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="b">
   <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="FirstCtrl" class="content" data-role="content" data-theme="d">
    <ul id="servicelist" >
         <li ng-repeat="serviceUser in serviceUsers" >
           <a data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"  data-transition="slide">
           <h3> {{serviceUser.Title}} {{serviceUser.Forename}} {{serviceUser.Surname}}  </h3>
           <p> Date of Birth: <strong>{{serviceUser.DOB}}</strong></p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>Room: {{serviceUser.Room}}</strong></p>
        </a>     
     </li>         

  </ul>   </div></div>
```

With the outermost div tag intact i cant see any values in my angular js objects but as soon as i remove my outer most div tag i start seeing the values but the page design and layout gets messed up.
I have imported angular.js, app.js, ServiceUserListCtrl.js(which has the firstctrl) into my page.  I have also included jquery-mobile-angular-adapter.js into my page but that also does not help much.
I have also created a directive

```
app.directive('app.directives', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
        elm.trigger('create');
    }
};});
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I don't see closing `</div>` tags in your code sample, do those exist in your real code base?

Comment: thank you for pointing that out have made the change